# thread blocked on process.stdout.read after another thread tried to close() it

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, blocking

I have two threads, one wants to interrupt the other.

Thread 1:

```
self.running = True

p = subprocess.Popen (... stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

self.closer = p.stdout

print ("Starting to read.")

while True:
    line = p.stdout.read ()
    if not line:
        print ("Finishing")
        break

self.running = False
```

Thread 2

```
print ("About to close.")

self.closer.close ()

while self.running:
    time.sleep (0.1)

print ("Finished")
```

This didn't work. The output is

```
Starting to read.
About to close.
```

Looks like `p.stdout.read()` is still blocked.

Some time later, `p.stdout.read()` throws an exception

```
ValueError: PyMemoryView_FromBuffer(): info->buf must not be NULL
```

Also, I think Thread 2's `close()` blocks until this exception.

What's the correct way to interrupt a thread which is reading from a process in a blocking fashion?

Comment: While the selected answer did not help me, a workaround seems to be to add bufsize=0 to the Popen call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for `unix` system:

You need to allow `Thread 1` to check the state of the closed flag without waiting indefinitely to read, for example using `poll` object in a loop, like this:

```
import select
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen("ls -lah", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
poll_obj = select.poll()
poll_obj.register(process.stdout, select.POLLIN)  # ready for reading
closed = False
while not closed:
    if poll_obj.poll(1):
        line = process.stdout.readline()
        print(line)
```